# Lookup values in a collection

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

`ClearCollect(MyCollection, Split("A,B,C", ","))` returns:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? What do you mean by looking up each of those values into another table? Having an example would help.

Comment: @carlosfigueira sure, I've edited my question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [AddColumns function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-table-shaping) to add the 'Name' column into the result of the Split function, something along the lines of

```
ClearCollect(
    MyCollection,
    AddColumns(
        Split("A,B,C", ","),
        "Name",
        LookUp(MySharePointList, Id = Result, Name)))
```

Where 'MySharePointList' is your SP list; 'Id' would be the field of that list that you want to match with the 'A'/'B'/'C', and 'Name' is the field of the list that you want to extract.